# Electron - Async keyword in served content causes unexpected token

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a node server running a simple monopoly app and my electron app just loads the URL of the node server. The issue I'm running into is that there's some async functions in the javascript that runs the front end of the node server and when the electron app tries to use this script it throws an unexpected token for the async key word.

I've tried to set the Electron app to run using the Babel renderer but this had no effect so I'm not sure if I'm missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

async / await keyword are new syntax of JavaScript, and is not supported by Node versions older than version 7.6. Electron uses Node.js and Chrome therefore, you need to use a version of Electron that has node.js higher than 7.6.

To check with Node.js version your Electron is using, run the following js code with electron.exe

```js
console.log(process.version)
```

Check [Electron releases](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases) or [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron) on which newer version of Electron you can install.